# The EntityManager is closed,Doctrine\\ORM\\ORMException

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having the below error when trying to insert the data by try cache method

This is my try catch function

```
$cardid = new CarddetailsId($uuidGenerator->generate());
$cardnumber = self::getCardNumber(); //this is generated random numbers
$cardexistencetype = ($key == "giftCardSchemeData") ? "Physical" : "E-Card" ;
$otherdata = array('cardnumber' => $cardnumber, 'cardexistencetype' => $cardexistencetype, 'isgiftcard' => true , 'giftcardamount' => $preload['value'], 'expirymonths' => $preload['expiryMonths'], 'isloyaltycard' => false, 'loyaltypoints' => null, 'pinnumber' => 4627);
$output = $otherdata;

try {
     $commandBus->dispatch(
         new CreateCarddetails($cardid, $output)
     );
  }
catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
   self::generateCardFunctionForErrorException($cardid, $output, $commandBus);
 }
```

Card numbers is unique so I have called another function and reinsert the data

```
public function generateCardFunctionForErrorException($cardid, $data, $commandBus) {
            $cardnumber = self::getCardNumber();
            $data['cardnumber'] = $cardnumber;
            try {
              $commandBus->dispatch(
                  new CreateCarddetails($cardid, $data)
              );
            }
            catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
                 var_dump($e);
                self::generateCardFunctionForErrorException($cardid, $data, $commandBus);
            }
          }
```

CreateCarddetailsis called the command and initiate the repository function
Below is my repository function code

```
public function save(Carddetails $carddetails)
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($carddetails);
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
    }
```

My command handler function is

```
public function handleCreateCarddetails(CreateCarddetails $command)
    {
        $carddetails = new Carddetails($command->getCarddetailsId(), $command->getCarddetailsData());
        $this->carddetailsRepository->save($carddetails);
    }
```

Comment: Show the handler for "CreateCarddetails" - class that handles that command.

Comment: `public function handleCreateCarddetails(CreateCarddetails $command)
    {
        $carddetails = new Carddetails($command->getCarddetailsId(), $command->getCarddetailsData());
        $this->carddetailsRepository->save($carddetails);
    }` this is my commandhandler

Comment: An often amusing feature of the entity manager is that it is no longer usable after it throws an exception.  This is by design.  If you really want to recover from an exception then you need to create a new entity manager.

Answer (score 0):

Check for existence of `Carddetails` entity before saving new one with same value for your field with that `UniqueConstraint`.

For example, assuming that you have duplicate ID error:

```
public function handleCreateCarddetails(CreateCarddetails $command)
{
    $existingDetails = $this->carddetailsRepository->find($command->getCarddetailsId());
    if (!$existingDetails){
        $carddetails = new Carddetails($command->getCarddetailsId(), $command->getCarddetailsData());
        $this->carddetailsRepository->save($carddetails);
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('Already have Details with this ID');
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I am having the loop of minimum 2000 numbers in that each time if I check for an existence It can increase my request and response time.

Comment: @Tharunkumar Doctrine ORM is not quite good for bulk inserts. Use SQL instead.

Comment: Okay Thanks @svgrafov